# How can I search a database for tags relating to a post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, linq

I have a post and tag class

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tags == null)
            {
                _tags = new Collection<Tag>();
            }
            return _tags;
        }
        set { _tags = value; }
    }

    private ICollection<Tag> _tags;
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to search for posts by their tag.

Here is my Search method

```
    public ActionResult Search(int id)
    {

        var posts = from p in db.Posts
                    from t in db.Tags
                    where p.Tags.Contains(t)
                    select p;
        foreach (var post in posts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Post Name {0}", post.Title));
        }

    }
```

But this will definitely not work as p.Tags is a collection.

So how can I return a list of posts that contain a tag with the id given to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var posts = db.Posts.Where(p=>p.Tags.Any(t=>t.id==id));
```

Comment: Thank you, you legend. I was looking for contains when it should have been Any.

Comment: For the record this should work as well, but it's not nearly as clean or clear: `var posts = db.Posts.Where(p=>p.Tags.Select(t=>t.id).Contains(id));`